# load data from text file to popup menu

Tags: matlab, user-interface, popup

I'd like to load data from a text file to a popup menu:

```
function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
str=['path\list.txt'];
fileID = fopen (str,'r');
C = textscan(fileID,'%d %s','Delimiter',' ');
for i = 1:length(C)
    set(hObject,'String',{cellstr(C{2}(i))});
end
fclose(fileID);
```

But i get this error :

> Error using matlab.ui.control.UIControl/set
>   While setting the 'String' property of UIControl:
>   Cell arrays input to String property may only contain character and numeric matrices.
>
> Error in conceptsCharge>popupmenu1_CreateFcn (line 100)
>       set(hObject,'String',{cellstr(C{2}(i))});
>
> Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
>           feval(varargin{:});
>
> Error in conceptsCharge (line 42)
>       gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
>
> Error in @(hObject,eventdata)conceptsCharge('popupmenu1_CreateFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

The cell C looks like this :

[image: C]

[image: C{2}]

Comment: can you show what `C` looks like? Also, you seem to be overwriting the string displayed in the popup menu in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Benoit_11 look to the comment

Comment: This is because you are not sending the right input to the `String` property of  the `popupmenu`. You are sending a cell array of `cell` (not of `string` as you need). Besides, you do not need the `for` loop. Get rid of the loop and just use : `set(hObject, 'String',C{2} ) ;`

Comment: I correct it butanother error appears
Error using close (line 105)
Invalid figure handle.

Error in conceptsCharge>conceptsCharge_OutputFcn (line 75)
close(fileID);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 264)
        feval(gui_State.gui_OutputFcn, gui_hFigure, [], gui_Handles);

Error in conceptsCharge (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});